# Customize Symfony forms and get more control over validation process

Tags: php, doctrine, validation, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I use doctrine:generate-admin to build CRUD operations for one of my models called "Alumnos". I know that Symfony generate the views under /apps/site/modules/alumnos/views and I'm trying to customize the input fields using Twitter Bootstrap Framework. The _form.php file has this code:

```
<?php echo $form['nombres']->renderLabel() ?>
<?php echo $form['nombres']->renderError() ?>
<?php echo $form['nombres'] ?>
```

But I want to add a **(*)** to required fields, a class to input fields and also wrap errors inside `<div>` tags with properly markup. How I can achieve this?

Also (don't know if it's better to open a new question for this part) I six fields and need to achieve this:

- If the first three fields (less said 1,2,3) are populated with values then validation pass
- If the second three fields (less said 4,5,6) are populated with values the validation pass
- At least firs three fields or second three fields are required so in all cases 1,2,3 can't be empty or 4,5,6 can't be empty

How I deal with this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's only in one form, you can go the hacky way:
replace, `<?php echo $form['nombres']->renderLabel() ?>` with HTML, that simple ^^

For your second question, you need a post validator in your form to check several fields. Here is an example:
http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/cookbook/1_2/en/conditional-validator

Maybe look in the jobeet tutorial if there is a post validator example.

Comment: Thanks @francois I'll take a look and when all is working I accept your answer

Comment: @ReynierPM there is a good article for the label for required fields part http://kriswallsmith.net/post/144021872/symfony-denote-required-form-fields

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question you should look at http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms at the bottom of the page they describe how to create a new WidgetFormSchemaFormatter.

For the second part, as Francois said, use a post validator, or a custom validator.